# make views inside Layout match custom shape of layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom semicircle Liner Layout in which I want to add colored views , but these views do not match the custom shape(or stay within the bounds of the Liner Layout)

When I assigned custom shape to the views

[custom shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzhWX.png)

when I assign MATCH_PARENT to the views

[match parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sVt1.png)

I want the views to fill the inside of the Liner Layout while retaining the shape of it, is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a custom shape to a view.  VIews are always rectangular.  If you mean you have a custom background, that doesn't make the view group a custom shape, or effect the layout of views within the group.  If you want to do that, you need to override onLayout (and possibly onMeasure) and layout the individual children with the bounds you expect them to be in.  Do not be surprised if you get some ugly or non-functional results like this-  views weren't made to be circular.

Comment: Is there any way I cloud make sure the view does not extend out of its parent? I have tried android:clipChildren="true" but that does not seem to work.

Comment: They can't expand out of their parent.  But their parent is a rectangle, not whatever shape your background drawable is.